# Migrating to new rooted phone, how do you restore from your titanium backup from the saved cloud backups

Tags: data-transfer, titanium-backup

I just purchased a new phone and rooted it to android 7.1 and i'm coming from android 6. I backed up my apps via titanium backup to my dropbox cloud. How can I restore all these apps on my new device from those titanium backup files? Or is there a better way to restore a setup like this? I need these apps as they have specific settings and can't just be downloaded again.

Answer (score 1):

From [TiBu FAQ](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-technical-faq.html)

> How can I restore my backups from Dropbox ....

**With Titanium Backup 3.6.4 (or above):**

> If your backup folder is empty, then with you can simply switch to the Schedules tab and hit the “RUN” button in the “Sync to Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive” section to download all backups from Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive back onto your phone.

**With older Titanium Backup versions:**

> Do not use the “Sync to Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive” button now: it’s a one-way sync and would erase your Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive files because you have no backups on the phone.
>   You need to copy the “TitaniumBackup” folder back from Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive onto your SD card:
>   On a computer, login to Dropbox / Box.net / Google Drive on the web
>
> - Click on the “TitaniumBackup” folder
> - Click on “Download folder”.
>
> Extract the ZIP file that you just downloaded.
>   Move the resulting “TitaniumBackup” folder from your computer onto your SD card
>
> Make sure USB mass storage is disabled (ie: your phone is disconnected from the computer)
>   Launch Titanium Backup and it should see your backups.

**Note:** Before restoring do check that the apps that you want to restore are not system apps in the new OS. If they are, don't restore them but manually apply those settings to avoid conflicts and problems in running them

**Edit**  Thanks to Izzy for adding inputs:

> Bold and underline to the final warning concerning system apps! I'd even be careful restoring their data. If you really need to, make sure you've enabled "migration mode" in settings, or you might screw up things (happened to me once).
>
> Some background: a normal restore e.g. simply *replaces* database files. Especially between different devices/ROMs, their structure might have changed – thus a replace (with the wrong structure) might cause the app to simply crash and refuse doing its job. Migration mode instead doesn't replace the file, but tries to match the data contained to the new/different structures.